# Generic class parent

Tags: java, generics

According to the [Generics trial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html),

[This section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) states:

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), `MyClass<A>` has no relationship to `MyClass<B>`, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` is Object.

Yet, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) we're told,

> Although Integer is a subtype of Number, `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` and, in fact, these two types are not related. The common parent of `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` is `List<?>`.

Why isn't the parent of `MyClass<A>` / `MyClass<B>` in the first example `MyClass<?>`? What is the distinction?

Comment: List of `?` means list of any .

Comment: Nice question. Looking forward to some great answers.

Comment: Well it doesn't get much more general than `Object` in Java does it? Consider what `Something<? extends Object>` means...

Comment: Object is raw parent, class<?> is generic parent.

Comment: I am surprised no one has mentioned type erasure thus far. If you are trying to understand Generics it is very important to understand type erasure. Even though `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` are not `related` as is states, at runtime BOTH become `MyClass<Object>` and therefore at runtime they are mutually castable (which could of course lead to bad things).

Comment: @JohnB good point. Compiler saves us once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is rather trivial. While the correct parent of `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` *is* indeed `MyClass<?>`, the tutorial did a small simplification there, as wildcards have not been introduced yet.

The point of saying

> The common parent of `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` is `Object`.

was just to make it clear that none of the two types is the parent of the other, regardless of the relationship between `A` and `B`.

This is confirmed by the following comment right below your first quote:

> For information on how to create a subtype-like relationship between two generic classes when the type parameters are related, see Wildcards and Subtyping.

as well as by the introduction of the chapter [Wildcards and Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html):

> As described in Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes, generic classes or interfaces are not related merely because there is a relationship between their types. However, you can use wildcards to create a relationship between generic classes or interfaces.

Comment: Does the compiler treat `MyClass<?>` as `MyClass<Object>`?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro Yes. Each generic type is replaced by the upper bound that is declared for that type. Having a `MyClass<?>` implies that the declaration of `MyClass` looks like this:
`class MyClass<T>`.
As `T` has no upper bound, `MyClass<?>` is `MyClass<Object>` at runtime. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html for more information.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro Actually, maybe I misunderstood you. `MyClass<?>` is *erased* to `MyClass<Object>`. But at compile time (before erasure), the two types are not completely equivalent. Wildcards are actually pretty complicated, so if you have any more questions about this, you should create a new question on SO. But first check if you find similar questions that have already been answered.

Comment: @rolve: I think `MyClass<?>` would be erased to `MyClass`

Comment: @newacct Yes, you're right. I wanted to say something like: Every `?` in `MyClass<?>` is erased to `Object`. But the JLS or the tutorials certainly have better formulations for this.

Answer (score 4):

Immediately after the first quote from the tutorial it says:

> For information on how to create a subtype-like relationship between
>   two generic classes when the type parameters are related, see Wildcards
>   and Subtyping.

which is a link to your second quote.

So, although I do think it is misleading and not very well-worded, I would read the first one as

> The common parent of MyClass and MyClass *would be* Object, if
>   it wasn't for our ability to do wildcards/sub-typing described in the following link

Comment: PS - not sure if this is an answer, but a comment wouldn't let me put the formatting in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really useful to talk about a single "parent" for a parameterized type. What matters is whether one thing is a supertype of the other. Sure, `Object` is a common supertype of `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>`, and so is `MyClass<?>`. If A and B are Integer and Number, then `MyClass<? extends Number>` is also a common supertype; so is `MyClass<? extends Serializable>`.

Comment: Right, the Java type "hierarchy" with interfaces is not a tree-like structure. But I think if we don't consider interfaces, there is something like a "lowest common supertype" of two (parametrized) types, which would then be their "parent". But this notion is not of great practical value.